# JBehave Error in POM! Multiple annotations found..: - Missing artifact org.jbehave:jbehave-core:zip:resources:3.5- SNAPSHOT:compile..etc

Tags: testing, maven, pom.xml, jbehave, scenarios

I am using JBehave for Scenario Testing.
while using tutorials i am getting error like below in **pom.xml**

```
Missing artifact org.jbehave:jbehave-core:zip:resources:3.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
Missing artifact org.jbehave:jbehave-spring:jar:3.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
Missing artifact org.jbehave:jbehave-core:jar:3.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

But i used pom.xml what they have supplied. 
i need to do any extra Settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the [docs](http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/running-examples.html) you will need to add `-Djbehave.version=[version]` or to add the Codehaus snapshot repository. There is more information at the doc page.

Comment: Hi, @Larrys i tried all the ways, given in the [doc](http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/running-examples.html) but still it's not working. do you tried any spring example? (with working state).

Comment: I've not run the examples, but by using the code in the examples you might be able to try it yourself in a sample project, which is what I did, but no longer have it laying around. Have you tried emailing the users list about your problems running examples?

Comment: i didn't try to emailing the users list yet.